# Drush doesn't download module version specified as dependency

Tags: 7, drush

My module has a dependency to specific version of [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module *(7.x-2.0-alpha4)* and I have specified that in my *info* file as documented in [Writing module .info files (Drupal 7.x)](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202#dependencies) documentation, just like this:

```
name = mymodule
description = MyModule description.
package = Media

dependencies[] = file_entity
dependencies[] = media (7.x-2.0-alpha4)
dependencies[] = media_internet
dependencies[] = views
```

When I try to enable my module with it's dependencies `drush en -y mymodule`, Drush downloads current stable version of `media` module *(7.x-1.5)* instead of the specified one and then enabling my module fails because of unmet dependency. I'm doing this on plain Drupal installation v7.34, DevDesktop stack v 2 RC build Mar 18 2015, Drush v7.0.0-alpha9 (from DevDesktop).

I have also tried to specify the version as `(2.0-alpha4)` and `(2.x)` - without success.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Drush download code actually pre-dates this feature; as you have observed, it is not supported.

I have posted a feature request in the Drush issue queue, here:

https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1285

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Greg! I'll watch the issue on GitHub as well.

Answer (score 1):

As @greg_1_anderson says, this feature is not supported yet, so such a dependency has to be downloaded and enabled in two steps

```
drush dl media-7.x-2.0-alpha4
....
drush en mymodule
```

Just running `drush en -y mymodule` will fail on unmet dependency.